# Data analysis in python

Tags: python, statistics, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-analysis

I have to make two data analysis reports using descriptive statistics, making plenty of informative plots etc.

Problem is, I'm not sure what tools should I use? I started preparing one report in Jupyter Notebook using pandas, scipy.stats and matplotlib with intention to convert it somehow to pdf later on, so I can have report without code. After hour or two I realized it might not be the best idea. I even had problem with making good description of categorical data, since pandas `describe()` had limited functionality on this type of data.

Could you suggest me some tools that would be best in this case? I want to prepare aesthetic, informative report. It's my first time doing data analysis including preparing report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your report doesn't require code, as you said. So why not just type up your report on Word and include the relevant tables and plots? You can produce plots on python using matplotlib ([seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) for aesthetic plots). And as for the statistics, you do not only have to use what pandas offers. Depending on the kind of data, for example, you can use [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) those functions on columns of your dataframe to generate insights.

Also check out this data analysis and visualization software called [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/). You can quickly create some beautiful and insightful plots using this; however, there is a learning curve.